# Neo4j - index lookup issue

Tags: search, indexing, neo4j, lucene

I was trying to set index type from exact to fulltext in neo4j shell, so i can do incasesensitive search with lucene query. So i used this command:

```
index --set-config Destination type fulltext
```

but it didn't work. Still couldn't do case insensitive search, so a played around and change some other values, like _blueprints:type and to_lower_case.
That didn't do any good.

Now it somehow ignores first character of name value ( weird ! ) . So if i am searching for "London" for example and i type "Lon" it returns nothing. But if i type "ond" it returns the node. The same for every node.

I tried setting everything back to normal. Didn`t help.

What did i mess up? What am i missing?

I am using a Everyman PHP library to communicate with database.

Comment: i think when you change it to the fulltext, than just the new entities are being searched fulltext. the old entities remain with old configs.

Answer (score 1):

I created new index with "to_lower_case" property.
I think that will solve my problem, just have to convert string to lower case before inserting it into query. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting configuration afterwards doesn't update already indexed values (as the shell notes, I think). If you've created your index with "to_lower_case=true" then additions as well as queries will have the values converted to lower case. Calling Index#get will still require you to lower-case it yourself.